# Apache VirtualHost directive ProxyPass

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I want to use Apache as a proxy for two different sites hosted on different machines. I am currently running Apache 2.2.15.

What I want to achieve is:

```
 Client --> https://ApacheWebProxyPubIP:443
        --> /Url1.php --> http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php
        --> /Url2 --> http://10.0.0.3/Url2
```

I tried using:

```
     VirtualHost default:443
         ServerName something.nice.org
         ProxyPass /Url1.php http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php
         ProxyPassReverse /Url1.php http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php
     VirtualHost
     VirtualHost *:443
         ServerName somethingelse.nice.org
         ProxyPass /Url2 http://10.0.0.3/Url2
         ProxyPassReverse /Url2 http://10.0.0.3/Url2
     VirtualHost *:443
```

The /Url1.php to http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php works fine but Url2 is not forwarded to 10.0.0.3.

What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If the Client is typing `ApacheWebProxyPubIP`, then VirtualHost with`ServerName somethingelse.nice.org` will never be used

Comment: But both something and somethingelse resolves to the same single public IP and both depend on the same port. How can I then point /Url1.php somewhere and /Url2 somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `<VirtualHost>` directive:

```
     ServerName something.nice.org
     ServerAlias somethingelse.nice.org

     ProxyPass /Url1.php http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php
     ProxyPassReverse /Url1.php http://10.0.0.2/Url1.php

     ProxyPass /Url2 http://10.0.0.3/Url2
     ProxyPassReverse /Url2 http://10.0.0.3/Url2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

directive.
Tells the forwarding server to preserve the host name (which is forwarded by the client).

Comment: Syntax: ProxyPreserveHost On|Off